# Invoke a base class constructor from the other module

Tags: c++

Let I've two `.cpp` files: `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` which contains classes defenition as the following:

```
//a.cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(){ \\some actions }
}
//b.cpp
class A;

class B : A
{
public:
    B():A(){ \\some actions }
}
```

But during the compile time I've an error. The error's description is:

> ConcreteSubject.cpp:5:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class
>   Subject’ ConcreteSubject.cpp:3:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class
>   Subject’ ConcreteSubject.cpp: In constructor
>   ‘ConcreteSubject::ConcreteSubject()’: ConcreteSubject.cpp:21:38:
>   error: type ‘Subject’ is not a direct base of ‘ConcreteSubject’

Is it possible to avoid `#include "a.cpp"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move class declaration of A to a header file and include that header file in you `b.cpp` file. If you don't do this, b.cpp compilation unit has no way to know the list of constructors implemented (explicitly or implicitly) by classs A.

Including a cpp file is not a good idea. You should not do this.

```
//a.h
class A
{
public:
    A();
}

//a.cpp
A::A(){ \\some actions }

//b.cpp
#include "a.h"

class B : A
{
public:
    B():A(){ \\some actions }
}
```